# How to retrieve data based on system date/ time

Tags: sql

I am working with a  Table which does NOT have a date/ time inserted column, is it possible to have a syntax that can pull the data using the script based on system date and time?

I also want a script to export Firebird data to excel, i used the one below but not working.

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET (
    'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
    'Excel 8.0;Database=c:\Test.xls;',
    'SELECT s.descr, 
      SUM(s.unitqty) AS sum_of_unitqty 
      FROM saleslines s GROUP BY s.descr'
)
```

Comment: This sounds like two separate questions.

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  My inclination, though is to say, "no, it is not possible".  You can't pull rows back by columns that don't exist (in most cases).

Comment: Based on system date and time? So all returned records will have the current date and time or what are you referring to? If it is not stored/recorded when the record was created or modified, then you don't have data to return it.

Comment: Which dbms? If possible to solve, product specific functionality must probably be used...